# Determine which app version to send apple push notification to (free or paid-for app version)

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

We have two versions of our app (free and paid-for), and we want to support push notifications for both of them, and they are both using the same server.

So far we can update the user data on the server, so if the user changes from the free to the paid version, we update the server and the user will start receiving push notifications to the paid-for version.

However, I've seen updates for apps in the past, that had a negative impact on the paid-for version, and people have downgraded to the free version.
It's a rare situation, however how can this be handled?

The logic we use to register the token is as follows:
We store the token and a confirmation in the user settings (AppDefaults).
When the user enables push notifications, we check if the app have these settings registered (notification_token and notification_token_confirmed_by_server).
If we have a token, but it's not confirmed by the server (as in the first time you enable push notification for the app) we send the token to the server along with what version of the app it is.

So if the user have both the paid for version on their phone, and the free version, and choose to use the free version for whatever reason, after upgrading the paid-for version, what is the best way to handle a scenario like this?

I saw one app called Draw Something, that was asking the user to uninstall the free version, but I think that's a terrible solution (you can't 'ask' your user to do anything and base your logic on that!)

Comment: Have you find any solution regarding to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the end was to send push notifications to the app version the user last signed in with.

You could alternatively update the server every time the user makes a request assuming you include the application version in the request, however this becomes "chatty" so in the interest of not hitting the database constantly it's a small price to pay